# Is there any Java ORM framework other than hibernate-spatial to deal with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, hibernate-spatial

I have been using hibernate-spatial to interact with postgis tables having Geography as a column. All content have been saved successfully using the hibernate-spatial but when we try to load the data from the postgis table then following got following exception:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject
I have checked the hibernate-spatial code and found that exception is thrown by toJTS(Object object) method of PGGeometryValueExtractor as Geography is not handled in code. 
Is there any way to read the postgis Geography object using hibernate-spatial.